# Enable register page only after I logged in - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using make:auth method in laravel 5.4. Now, I want to change the behavior of the Register option. I want to have the register option only for users who logged in as Admin and for other users the register option should be disabled. The original version allows you to register before being authenticated. I want to use this register option to make admin to add new users.
I tried option of authenticating user and redirect to register page in home.blade.php but it doesn't work. I am learning laravel for my new project.So any expert advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's a method like this in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

This is currently making it so that only users who are *not* logged in can access the page. Instead, let's change that to meet the needs of one of your criteria:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Great, now they must be logged in to access it. But what about being an Admin? Let's make that Middleware, now:

```
php artisan make:middelware AdminMiddleware
```

Now let's open the file at `App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware` and make some adjustments.

**Note** I have to make some assumptions about your codebase here.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Next, let's register our application middleware. Open up `App\Http\Kernel.php` and scroll to the bottom:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class, // <--add this
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Finally let's go back to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` and update our `construct` function to utilize this middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);
}
```

Now your user must be logged in, and they also must have a role of `admin`.

There's surely shorter ways to get this done, but this is a method that I prefer as it will help you from repeating yourself (DRY programming).

Answer (score 0):

It really helped.changes in `App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;                                                    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin == 1) 
    { 
        return $next($request);
    }      

    return redirect('home'); 

    }
```

Have a field named 'is_admin' in users table.And other changes in file as you said. 
Now in public page(http://localhost/larashop/public/) , here login and register both links are visible. 
 1. when I click on Login ,it redirects to login page : here I enter a admin email id , it doesn't display me the register option neither for non admin users. 
2. when I click on Register,it redirects to login page :
  Here,I enter admin email id ,it redirects to register page and for non admin users it redirects to home page.this works fine.
So, the login link doesn't work as expected.Any suggestions

```
 `
```